# creating a batch file to open a program in a non-default state

Tags: windows-xp, batch

Is it possible to create a batch file that would open a program in a non-default state?

For example I would like to open firefox and the web console tool located in Tools->Web developer in Firefox 28.0

Answer (score 0):

Unless it is supported by the command line or configuration options for a program then no, you cannot simply open a program in a way that is non-default.

What you can do though is to use a keyboard/mouse scripting program such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) with which you can run a program then send the relevant key and mouse clicks necessary to get the program into the state that you require.

These two programs might take a little learning to achieve what you are after but then would do what you need.

Autohotkey also has [several script writers](http://www.autohotkey.net/~faqbot/faq.html#recorders) that you can use to record a series of keyboard and mouse clicks into a script for you, saving you time and effort learning the syntax.  A program that I have seen some recommendations for (but not personally used) is [Pulover's Macro Creator](http://www.macrocreator.com/download/).